# Can pointers be a data structure?

Tags: c++

Can pointers be considered an efficient and semantic-wise data structure? How can it stackup against linked list, hash, queus, stack?

Comment: I don't know, how *does* an integer stack up to data structures?

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe. Is USA a democracy or a republic? Is California sparkling wine Champagne? Your question is one of word definition, not code. You certainly can consider pointers as data structures. Equally, you could consider them distinct from data structures. Voting to close.

Comment: @Chris: Integer is composed of bits that are stored in the memory cell. Cell itself may consists of transistors (six transistors in SRAM case, for example), or it could be some combination of latches. Cells themselves are also structured to form a memory bank. There are buses, interconnects, translation tables etc. So how is integer not a data structure?

Comment: @VladLazarenko my mind is blowing *as we speak*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, a pointer is just a type, not a structure. There are implementations of structures that are types (`std::vector`, `std::map`, ...), but a pointer is not.

They are commonly used internally in the implementations of the structures you enumerated, but in itself, a pointer is not a structure.

Comment: You can sometimes, on some architectures pack information into a pointer if you're careful. (Probably not worth the hassle, but still possible)

Comment: Not just on some architectures, there are implementations of doubly linked lists with a single pointer by xor-ing the next and last pointers. You just need to maintain two pointers while iterating so that you can *decode* the pointer in a node. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that sounds sci-fi. But anyway, the data structure is a double linked list, not a pointer. How it's implemented is a different issue.

Comment: Also, the first sentence does not really mean anything. A `std::map<int,int>` is a type, and it is also a data structure. The question is, as Rob points in the comments above one of naming, *what is a data structure*? What properties make a type a data structure or not?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas as for the first sentence, you're right, could have formulated it better.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Same difference... the wikipedia article is quite arbitrary. What makes `bool` a data structure and not `int*`? Also note that `Plain old data` is mentioned as a data type, and the fact is that all arithmetic types and pointers are cathegorized as `POD` in the C++ standard. Again, the question makes no sense until a proper definition of what a data structure is is provided. Additionally, note that if you follow your link to the definition of data structure in wikipedia, that definition does not seem to include primitive types.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I never said primitive types were data structures. They are not.

Comment: :) You did not, the article you link to does. Anyway, there is no point in discussing, this is a case of what you want to call by what name. *"What's in a name? That which we call a rose
by any other name would smell as sweet."*

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a data *type*, not a data structure (although some books with rather loose terminology will define fundamental types such as pointers as elements of the larger set of data structures; regardless, a pointer is certainly not an example of an *abstract* data structure.)

More pertinently, most C++ implementations of abstract data structures such as linked lists, queues, stacks, trees, and so forth will employ pointers as data *members*; that is, **pointers will form part of the implementation**; they are not the implementation itself.

As an example, if you're thinking about implementing your own linked list, you might choose to have a doubly linked version, where each element in the list is represented by a node containing pointers to the previous and next nodes:

```
template <typename T>
class DLList
{
public:
    // Lots of things
private:
    Node* _head; // Pointer to the head of the list
    Node* _tail; // Pointer to the tail of the list
};
```

Your node might then be implemented like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    Node* _prev;
    Node* _next;
    T     _data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A data structure is a particular way of storing and organizing data in a computer so that it can be used efficiently. Pointer is indeed a very efficient way of storing and organizing data and is a primary way of addressing memory these days. It is not the only way, though. For example, CPU registers are addressed differently. So the answer to the first question is yes.

As for your second question, you cannot really compare pointers with higher-level data structures like hash, queues, stacks and others. These are two different levels of abstraction. Higher level containers are implemented using lower-level data structures like pointers.